# VBA: Sort array based on another array

Tags: arrays, vba, sorting, excel

I have several very long arrays which need to be sorted alphabetically based on user action, but for simplicity I'll use the following example:

```
Dim Name as Variant, Street as Variant
Name = array("B", "C", "D", "A", "E")
Street = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")
```

After the user clicks the sorting button, the `Name` array now has the following order

```
("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
```

and I then need to sort the `Street` array, so it gets the corresponding order, i.e.

```
("4", "1", "2", "3", "5")
```

**What is the most efficient way to do this in VBA?**

*Please notice*: I know how to sort an individual array normally in VBA, I'm only looking for answers that involve sorting an array based on another array. Thanks.

Comment: Why not a 2D Array? How do you sort a normal Array? Do you have some code that does it? If so, please could you share that?

Comment: Sorting an array in VBA is hardly news, but since you ask, I use the excellent qsort algorithm by Chip Pearson for that, http://www.cpearson.com/excel/SortingArrays.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to do what you want:

```
Sub MAIN()
    Dim Name(), Street()
    Name = Array("B", "C", "D", "A", "E")
    Street = Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")

    Call sort2(Name(), Street())

    For Each s In Street
        MsgBox s
    Next s
End Sub


Sub sort2(key() As Variant, other() As Variant)
Dim I As Long, J As Long, Low As Long
Dim Hi As Long, Temp As Variant
    Low = LBound(key)
    Hi = UBound(key)

    J = (Hi - Low + 1) \ 2
    Do While J > 0
        For I = Low To Hi - J
          If key(I) > key(I + J) Then
            Temp = key(I)
            key(I) = key(I + J)
            key(I + J) = Temp
            Temp = other(I)
            other(I) = other(I + J)
            other(I + J) = Temp
          End If
        Next I
        For I = Hi - J To Low Step -1
          If key(I) > key(I + J) Then
            Temp = key(I)
            key(I) = key(I + J)
            key(I + J) = Temp
            Temp = other(I)
            other(I) = other(I + J)
            other(I + J) = Temp
          End If
        Next I
        J = J \ 2
    Loop
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

To add more arrays to the mix, just include them in the header and insert more lines like:

```
            Temp = other2(I)
            other2(I) = other2(I + J)
            other2(I + J) = Temp
```

in **both** places in the sort routine.

Comment: Looks interesting. I'll test and get back.

Comment: Works well, I'll mark as accepted. What do you suppose would be the easiest way to extend this to work with several arrays to be sorted at once based on just one?

Comment: @Miqi180..................If I had many arrays, I would be tempted to stuff them into worksheet columns and use Excel's native sort.

Comment: Yeah, that would make the coding easier but I can't do that here. I need the arrays to be sorted as quickly as possible and accessing the document slows things down, even if you turn the screenupdating off.

Comment: Just tested the augmented code with 5 arrays at once. Works great. Thanks!

Comment: This is a gorgeous algorithm. Thank you.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Actually, just spotted a possible error with the algorithm. When you sort ```1 2 3 4 5 6``` based on ```11 10 9 12 7 5```, the output is ```6 5 3 1 2 4``` instead of ```6 5 3 2 1 4```.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent but if you change ```11 10 9 12 7 5``` to ```12 10 9 13 7 5```, it works fine.