# Excel macro to sort data by word count in one column and expanding to other data columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have a data worksheet of 11 columns and over 6000 rows. I need to sort column F by the number of words in each cell, smallest to largest, expanding the sort to the entire data in 11 columns.

Can this be achieved? Appreciating any assistance in this matter.

Comment: Yes, it can be achieved. See [Why is 'Can someone help me?' not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below variant based on assumption that your data table in range "A:K" (as you mentioned 11 columns). Replace "Sheet1" to the sheet name with your data

```
Sub sort_by_words_count()
    Dim Cl As Range, S() As String, i&
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        i = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
        For Each Cl In .Range("F2:F" & i)
            S = Split(WorksheetFunction.Trim(Cl.Value))
            Cl.Value = Right("0000" & UBound(S()) + 1, 4) & "|" & Cl.Value
        Next Cl
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("A1:K" & i).AutoFilter
        .AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add _
            Key:=Range("F1:F" & i), _
            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
            Order:=xlAscending, _
            DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            With .AutoFilter.Sort
                .Header = xlYes
                .MatchCase = False
                .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                .Apply
            End With
        For Each Cl In .Range("F2:F" & i)
            Cl.Value = Split(Cl.Value, "|")(1)
        Next Cl
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 1
End Sub
```

**sheet before sort**

[image]

**sheet after sort**

[image]

Comment: This is fabulous Vasily. I ran the code and it worked as expected and actually over expected as it sorted Col F in this order 1,10,11,12... 2,21,22 ...3,31,32...etc. Is it possible to get it sorted in an ascending order 1,2,3..10,11,12...20,21,22..etc instead? Very much appreciated.

Comment: @JosefMiller sure) post has been updated, now it works as you expected ... I guess)

Comment: Very impressive Vasily, the very exact result is reached by running the second version of the code. Thank you very much for your invaluable input which I'm sure will benefit lots of other people. All the best.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution would be to use worksheet formula as suggested in [Microsoft support artice kb213889](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/213889).  If you are prepared to assume the deliminator is a ' ' for example and that the column will only contain valid words, in row L you could add a sort-index column with the following formula:

```
=IF(F1=TRIM(""),-1,LEN(TRIM(F1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(F1)," ","")))
```

There are several options for sorting on the basis of the indexed column e.g. VBA (e.g. [Steve Bullen's QuickSort()](http://www.oaltd.co.uk/excel/)) or using standard Excel sorting functionality.

If you insist on doing the entire calculation in VBA a possible solution would be to read the entire array into a variant and append an addition column onto the array and again use the QuickSort() algorithm above to sort the array. A simple function to count the number of words could be:

```
'count words in input string - assume only words passed in
Public Function CountWords(vInput As Variant, Optional sDelim As String = " ") As Integer
Dim iWordCount as integer
Dim sString as string


    sString = Trim$(vInput)

    If Len(sString) = 0 Then
        iWordCount = 0
    ElseIf InStr(1, sString, sDelim) = 0 Then
        iWordCount = 1
    Else
         'return array 0 based
         iWordCount = UBound(VBA.Split(sString, sDelim)) + 1
    End If

    CountWords = iWordCount

End
```

Comment: You can also add just the column with `=IF(F1=TRIM(""),-1,LEN(TRIM(F1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(F1)," ","")))`, and then sort by the menu function, expanding the selection area.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming names are in column B, this macro puts all cells including both "Jon" and "Smith" into an array.  Another array is created to show how many words are in each array element.  The sort2 sub is then called to sort myArr by wordCountarr

I found Sort2 sub [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29923742/vba-sort-array-based-on-another-array) , it was written by member Gary's Student and appears to work flawlessly.

```
Sub create2arr()
Dim myArr() As Variant, name1 As String, name2 As String, firstMarker As Boolean, myArrayCounter As Long, myArray2Counter As Long
Dim splitArr() As String, wordCountArr() As Variant

name1 = "Jon"
name2 = "Smith"
ReDim myArr(1 To 1)
ReDim myArr2(1 To 1)
ReDim wordCountArr(1 To 1)

myArrayCounter = 1
myArray2Counter = 1

For I = 1 To 3
   splitArr = Split(Sheet6.Range("B" & I))
   For J = LBound(splitArr) To UBound(splitArr)
        If splitArr(J) = name1 Or splitArr(J) = name2 Then
                If firstMarker = True Then
                    myArr(myArrayCounter) = Sheet6.Range("B" & I)
                    wordCountArr(myArrayCounter) = UBound(splitArr) + 1
                    myArrayCounter = myArrayCounter + 1
                    ReDim Preserve myArr(1 To myArrayCounter)
                    ReDim Preserve wordCountArr(1 To myArrayCounter)
                    firstMarker = False
                Else
                    firstMarker = True
                End If
        End If
    Next J
Next I

For I = 1 To UBound(myArr)
Debug.Print myArr(I)
Next I

Call sort2(wordCountArr, myArr)

For I = 1 To UBound(myArr)
Debug.Print myArr(I)
Next I


End Sub

Sub sort2(key() As Variant, other() As Variant)
Dim I As Long, J As Long, Low As Long
Dim Hi As Long, Temp As Variant
    Low = LBound(key)
    Hi = UBound(key)

    J = (Hi - Low + 1) \ 2
    Do While J > 0
        For I = Low To Hi - J
          If key(I) > key(I + J) Then
            Temp = key(I)
            key(I) = key(I + J)
            key(I + J) = Temp
            Temp = other(I)
            other(I) = other(I + J)
            other(I + J) = Temp
          End If
        Next I
        For I = Hi - J To Low Step -1
          If key(I) > key(I + J) Then
            Temp = key(I)
            key(I) = key(I + J)
            key(I + J) = Temp
            Temp = other(I)
            other(I) = other(I + J)
            other(I + J) = Temp
          End If
        Next I
        J = J \ 2
    Loop
End Sub
```