# Compare strings in a cell no matter the sequence

Tags: string, vba, excel, string-comparison

I am looking some help with a code to compare 2 strings and rank them in accordance of their matching with the original criteria.  The code should ignore the sequence, For example, A1 contains words "Jon Smith" (original value), and B1 "Smith Jon", which are the same ranking. But if C1 contains "Jon Smith Junior", this should have a lower rank than "Jon Smith" or "Smith Jon".

Any one can help?

Comment: You want a "Fuzzy Lookup" add in, there are many.  Microsoft has one.

Comment: Very usefull to know, thank you @ScottCraner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StackOverflow is not a coding service, and you should provide your code, but in this case I was interested in the task. Here is a possible solution.
Run the checkme - it simply takes the two strings and splits them into arrays. Then it counts how many times the values in arrOne present in arrTwo. With this information, it gives some kind of a result.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function CompareTwo(strOne As String, strTwo As String) As Double

    Dim arrOne      As Variant
    Dim arrTwo      As Variant
    Dim varOne      As Variant
    Dim varTwo      As Variant

    Dim lngCounter  As Long

    arrOne = Split(strOne)
    arrTwo = Split(strTwo)

    For Each varOne In arrOne
        For Each varTwo In arrTwo
            If varOne = varTwo Then
                lngCounter = lngCounter + 1
            End If
        Next varTwo
    Next varOne

    CompareTwo = lngCounter / (UBound(arrOne) + 1)

End Function

Public Sub CheckMe()

    Debug.Print CompareTwo("Smith Jon", "Jon Smith")
    Debug.Print CompareTwo("Jon Smith Junior", "Jon Smith")
    Debug.Print CompareTwo("Jon Smith Junior Ale 6", "Jon Smith Ale 6")

End Sub
```

Comment: This is great Vityata, many thanks! I am just starting and I did not know where to begin. my problem is actually a little bit more deeper than this. For example, I need a way to use .Dictionary in your suggested code. So for example "Jon Smith II" = "Jon Smith Second" = 1. Is there a way to add an additional layer of checking so it compares finds "II"="second".

Comment: In the case of `II` and `Second` an easy way to make it is to introduce a Replace the `II` with `Second` in both arrays. Take a look at this function - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt3szac5(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Thanks you @Vityata. I can use simple replace, but the problem is that this is different for different names. so when I loop this through the list of names, it won't find the name "III" as "Third"  or "Jnr" for "Junior" and so on. I need to make the varTwo flexible somehow, so it "matches" the strings for the list of pre-mapped names.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this one.  It creates two arrays, one where the two key names are found within a given cell in Column B, and another with how many words are in each array element of arr1.  Then it sends the two arrays to a Sort2 Sub, which was written by member Gary's Student and can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29923742/vba-sort-array-based-on-another-array). It presumes the multiple choice names are in column "B" and that "Jon" and "Smith" are hardcoded - but can be drawn from another column with a little change to the code.

Column B contains:
Jon Smith
Smith Jon Junior
Smith Jon

```
Sub create2arr()
Dim myArr() As Variant, name1 As String, name2 As String, firstMarker As Boolean, myArrayCounter As Long, myArray2Counter As Long
Dim splitArr() As String, wordCountArr() As Variant

name1 = "Jon"
name2 = "Smith"
ReDim myArr(1 To 1)
ReDim myArr2(1 To 1)
ReDim wordCountArr(1 To 1)

myArrayCounter = 1
myArray2Counter = 1

For I = 1 To 3
   splitArr = Split(Sheet6.Range("B" & I))
   For J = LBound(splitArr) To UBound(splitArr)
        If UCase(splitArr(J)) = UCase(name1) Or UCase(splitArr(J)) = UCase(name2) Then
                If firstMarker = True Then
                    myArr(myArrayCounter) = Sheet6.Range("B" & I)
                    wordCountArr(myArrayCounter) = UBound(splitArr) + 1
                    myArrayCounter = myArrayCounter + 1
                    ReDim Preserve myArr(1 To myArrayCounter)
                    ReDim Preserve wordCountArr(1 To myArrayCounter)
                    firstMarker = False
                Else
                    firstMarker = True
                End If
        End If
    Next J
Next I

For I = 1 To UBound(myArr)
Debug.Print myArr(I)
Next I

Call sort2(wordCountArr, myArr)

For I = 1 To UBound(myArr)
Debug.Print myArr(I)
Next I


End Sub

Sub sort2(key() As Variant, other() As Variant)
Dim I As Long, J As Long, Low As Long
Dim Hi As Long, Temp As Variant
    Low = LBound(key)
    Hi = UBound(key)

    J = (Hi - Low + 1) \ 2
    Do While J > 0
        For I = Low To Hi - J
          If key(I) > key(I + J) Then
            Temp = key(I)
            key(I) = key(I + J)
            key(I + J) = Temp
            Temp = other(I)
            other(I) = other(I + J)
            other(I + J) = Temp
          End If
        Next I
        For I = Hi - J To Low Step -1
          If key(I) > key(I + J) Then
            Temp = key(I)
            key(I) = key(I + J)
            key(I + J) = Temp
            Temp = other(I)
            other(I) = other(I + J)
            other(I + J) = Temp
          End If
        Next I
        J = J \ 2
    Loop
End Sub
```